# Refresh div without removing text selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, chat

I've built a simple chat that reloads every 3 seconds.

The actual reloading of the chat is done by this script (copied from Google, I've only done PHP, CSS and html before):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#chat").load("system/chat.oclog"); // Loads chat upon page load
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $("#chat").load("system/chat.oclog");
    }, 3000);                            
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

Now to the problem. If you were to select any text inside of the chat-div, the selection goes away when the chat reloads since the div is being refreshed. This makes copying text a real pain.

Any suggestions/solutions to this problem is greatly appreciated. Me myself have been thinking of maybe making the script only reload the chat if the filesize of the chatlog has changed, but I'm not sure how to to this and Google hasn't given me a solution either.

/Erik

Comment: google `textbox.size` or `length` + 'javascript'

Answer (score 1):

Solution :-

First Create 2 Div's ,  1 For loading content and it will hidden by css ( display : none ), and then a another one that will be visible to user,

```
<div id="hidden_content" style="display : none;">  </div>
<div id="chat">  </div>
```

And your content will be  load in hidden_content, and then add a another function that will         called everytime when content loaded in in hidden element, then you can check if the string length of hidden_content's div is equal to chat div's content, and if it is equal so no need to copy this data in chat div , and if not then you can will use substr to find out what new more chars are added in hidden_content, and then once you find out those more chars that was not in chat before, "append" them the chat content !

So by this only new chars will append to that chat, so you can select and it will not reload again :),  This solution will work if the loaded content increase like this :-

previous content + new content

Mean on server if There was one message on file and then a another added so this another one must be apped to that old one,

Well it's not a good solution at all, your browser will always dowload full data, and that is not good solution ! , Sorry for weak english :)